# Chrome SSL self sign certificate issue

Tags: .net, google-chrome, ssl, self-signed

I am developing my application on visual studio and chrome. I need to run the application on https. So I am using self-signed certificate from visual studio.

Everything worked fine till today. Today, I am getting the error net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE for every link in my website (every js and css file).

I have no idea what is causing it. Opening the link in separate window and accepting certificate is also not helping.

My version of chrome is: Version 44.0.2403.107 m

Please suggest something.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a bug in Chrome 44.0.2403.107 m, which was just released some days ago. Hopefully, the fix is already on the way: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=513903